# How to do an image half grayscale on the same window using opencv python?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I just want to do half will be gray. Actually, I used python opencv to do this on a

Comment: kindly see this  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  to know how to ask a question

Comment: Also create a [mcve], please.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question is not clear which language you are using. But if you are using python and opencv then you can use this simple code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('one.jpg');        # read color/rgb image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    # convert rgb image to gray

ind = np.int(gray.shape[1]/2)       # get width/2 value of the image for indexing
img[:,0:ind,0] = gray[:,0:ind]      # make blue component value equal to gray image
img[:,0:ind,1] = gray[:,0:ind]      # make green component value equal to gray image
img[:,0:ind,2] = gray[:,0:ind]      # make red component value equal to gray image

cv2.imshow('Result',img)        # show image result

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For using it on a video

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, img = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    # convert rgb image to gray

        ind = np.int(gray.shape[1]/2)       # get width/2 value of the image for indexing
        img[:,0:ind,:] = cv2.cvtColor(gray[:,0:ind], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

        cv2.imshow('Result',img)        # show image result
    else:
        break
    # check if escape key is pressed then break loop
    if (cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF) == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Just for adding to your answer, he can also do `img[:,0:ind] = cv2.cvtColor(gray[:,0:ind], cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) ` instead of doing the copy for each channel :) The result and probably the speed as well will be exactly the same, just 2 lines less

Comment: add this check `if ret==True:`